# I can't understand why my pd dataframe only returns the last row

Tags: pandas, list, function, loops, for-loop

im trying to turn this dictionary into a pd dataframe.  It should have 31 rows, but it only keeps creating the last row.  Here is the code...

```
for i, n in zip(list(df.actor_id), weighted_avg):
    ziplist = {i:n}
    print(ziplist)
```

df.actor_id is a column of strings from a dataframe and weighted_avg is list on numbers from a function.

```
pd.DataFrame(ziplist)'''
```

Comment: `ziplist` is overwritten with every iteration because it is assigned inside your loop. Just do: `ziplist = dict(zip(df['actor_id'], weighted_avg))`

Comment: awesome, thanks..I have a tendency to overcode then wonder what went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar in my code, first i have this Data frame

```
    WIS_REP_ID  DTC_DTC_ID
    2156061     EBS-U0100-87
    2156061     TGW-B1502-81
    2156061     TGW-B1002-13
    2053897     EMS-P203F-00
    2053897     EMS-P2BA7-00
...
```

Then i have a list of integers that i want to add as indexes:

```
weighted_avg = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

in this case my df is bigger so i used the head method to get only the top 10 values and then i verify by printing only the values of my row of interest:

```
dfactor_id= (DTCSheet.head(10))
print (dfactor_id["DTC_DTC_ID"])
```

​Applying your same loop:

```
for i, n in zip(list(dfactor_id["DTC_DTC_ID"]), weighted_avg):
    ziplist = {i:n}
    print(ziplist)
```

The output would be:

```
{'EBS-U0100-87': 0}
{'TGW-B1502-81': 1}
{'TGW-B1002-13': 2}
{'EMS-P203F-00': 3}
{'EMS-P2BA7-00': 4}
{'HMIIOM-U1153-71': 5}
{'AUDIO-B1013-21': 6}
{'FCIOM-C1093-11': 7}
{'APM-C1026-68': 8}
{'VMCU-C1013-73': 9}
```

However, you are overwriting ziplist, so you just need:

```
ziplist = []
for i, n in zip(list(dfactor_id["DTC_DTC_ID"]), weighted_avg):
    ziplist.append({i:n})
print(ziplist)
```

Comment: There is no need for any loops to accomplish what the OP wants. You only have to do `ziplist = dict(zip(df['actor_id'], weighted_avg))`